# .htaccess redirect a url to another (keep the url segments)

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

Need to redirect `http:// www.old-url.com/any/other/url/segment`
to `https:/ /www.new-url.com/any/other/url/segment`

Currently Im doing something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://www.old-url.com/1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new-url.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this results:

```
http:// www.old-url.com/any/other/url/segment to
https:// www.new-url.com/
```

Thanks
-Robbie

Answer (score 0):

Use below htaccess rule to redirect http to https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Source: [htaccess redirect](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/21-very-useful-htaccess-tips-tricks/)

Comment: This causes `Internal Server Error` for me